# Cognitive Behavior Therapy intensive in home clinical and therapeutic services model

Tags: anxiety, autism, therapy, cbt

I am looking for any information that shows the number of hours of CBT per week a child with autism, anxiety, and ADHD should be receiving.  Mostly looking for a range.  Prefer in NJ but will review any case studies done.  Also looking for case studies about therapy and multiple children in the household with developmental disabilities receiving therapy services.

I have three children with autism, ADHD, and anxiety.  My children receive limited services through PerformCare in our state.  Each child receives four hours per week.  These hours include an array of rehabilitation an/or habilitation services delivered face to face as a defined set of interventions by clinically licensed or certified practitioners. http://www.performcarenj.org/pdf/provider/clinicalcriteria/intensive-in-home-services.pdf.  Originally they were approved for 12 hours per child.  Then Performcare came in and said they were reducing their hours to 4 per week without a titration plan.  Their explanation was that they approved the number of hours by mistake.  I filed an appeal and am now in litigation pro se.

I am trying to respond to a motion where their attorney is saying the max amount of intensive in-home clinical and therapeutic services my child can receive are 4 hours per week. They have provided some information about information overload for a child but I am trying to advocate for my son's services.

After cutting the hours they were used to receiving my family went through a terrible regression.

Comment: We can't help with personal/individual issues here. If you need to justify the need for services you should start with the people providing the care. There might be advocacy groups in your area that can help you with pro se representation on this matter but we can't really provide legal advice here either.